# Calculating the amount of interactions with 3-way interactions

Tags: regression, interaction, combinatorics

How do I calculate how many 3-way interactions could be tested when there are five predictors included in the model (multiple linear regression analysis)?

And how many 5-way interactions could be tested when there are five predictors included in the model?

Comment: What do you think about my answer? If it is helpful and clear, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1):

- 3-way interactions among 5 regressors: the number of combinations of 3 from 5: $\begin{pmatrix}
  5 \\
  3
  \end{pmatrix}=\frac{5\cdot 4\cdot 3}{{3\cdot 2\cdot 1}}=10$.
- 5-way interactions among 5 regressors: there is but a single one! Or formally, the number of combinations of 5 from 5: $\begin{pmatrix}
  5 \\
  5
  \end{pmatrix}=\frac{5!}{{5!}}=1$.